# Using pure numpy metric as metric in Keras/TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a competition on Kaggle, where the evaluation metric is defined as

This competition is evaluated on the mean average precision at different intersection over union (IoU) thresholds. The IoU of a proposed set of object pixels and a set of true object pixels is calculated as:

```
              IoU(A,B)=(A∩B)/(A∪B)
```

The metric sweeps over a range of IoU thresholds, at each point calculating an average precision value. The threshold values range from 0.5 to 0.95 with a step size of 0.05: `(0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95)`. In other words, at a threshold of 0.5, a predicted object is considered a "hit" if its intersection over union with a ground truth object is greater than 0.5. At each threshold value t, a precision value is calculated based on the number of true positives `(TP)`, false negatives `(FN)`, and false positives `(FP)` resulting from comparing the predicted object to all ground truth objects:

```
                     TP(t)/TP(t)+FP(t)+FN(t).
```

A true positive is counted when a single predicted object matches a ground truth object with an IoU above the threshold. A false positive indicates a predicted object had no associated ground truth object. A false negative indicates a ground truth object had no associated predicted object. The average precision of a single image is then calculated as the mean of the above precision values at each IoU threshold:

```
           (1/|thresholds|)*∑tTP(t)/TP(t)+FP(t)+FN(t)
```

Now, I have written this function in pure numpy as it was much easier to code in that and I have decorated it with `tf.py_fucn()` in order to use with it with Keras. Here is the sample code:

```
def iou_metric(y_true_in, y_pred_in, fix_zero=False):
    labels = y_true_in
    y_pred = y_pred_in

    true_objects = 2
    pred_objects = 2

    if fix_zero:
        if np.sum(y_true_in) == 0:
            return 1 if np.sum(y_pred_in) == 0 else 0

    intersection = np.histogram2d(labels.flatten(), y_pred.flatten(), bins=(true_objects, pred_objects))[0]

    # Compute areas (needed for finding the union between all objects)
    area_true = np.histogram(labels, bins = true_objects)[0]
    area_pred = np.histogram(y_pred, bins = pred_objects)[0]
    area_true = np.expand_dims(area_true, -1)
    area_pred = np.expand_dims(area_pred, 0)

    # Compute union
    union = area_true + area_pred - intersection

    # Exclude background from the analysis
    intersection = intersection[1:,1:]
    union = union[1:,1:]
    union[union == 0] = 1e-9

    # Compute the intersection over union
    iou = intersection / union

    # Precision helper function
    def precision_at(threshold, iou):
        matches = iou > threshold
        true_positives = np.sum(matches, axis=1) == 1   # Correct objects
        false_positives = np.sum(matches, axis=0) == 0  # Missed objects
        false_negatives = np.sum(matches, axis=1) == 0  # Extra objects
        tp, fp, fn = np.sum(true_positives), np.sum(false_positives), np.sum(false_negatives)
        return tp, fp, fn

    # Loop over IoU thresholds
    prec = []

    for t in np.arange(0.5, 1.0, 0.05):
        tp, fp, fn = precision_at(t, iou)
        if (tp + fp + fn) > 0:
            p = tp / (tp + fp + fn)
        else:
            p = 0
        prec.append(p)

    return np.mean(prec)
```

I tried to convert it into pure `tf` function but was unable to do it as I am not able to figure out how the `control dependencies` would work out. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Have you considered using `pyfunc`?

Comment: I am using `tf.py_func()` only as of now

Comment: In your particular use case you could use the implementation by tensorflow: [`tf.metrics.mean_iou`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/mean_iou).

Answer (score 2):

To use your function you have to convert tensors and numpy arrays and the other way around.
To convert a tensor into a numpy array use `tf.eval` (see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#eval)):

```
np_array = tensor.eval()
```

If you want to convert a python object (also numpy array) into tensor you can use `tf.convert_to_tensor` (see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor)):

```
tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.mean(prec),dtype=tf.float32)
```